# Eloquent: My query is having information added by default?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I am trying to fetch some information from one if my databases. Everytime I run this query, it gives me an error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'users_friends.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `users_friends` where `users_friends`.`user_id` = 1 and
>   `users_friends`.`user_id` is not null and (`user_one` = 1 and
>   `user_two` = 2 and `0` = friendship_official and `1` = 0) or
>   (`user_one` = 2 and `user_two` = 1 and `0` = friendship_official and
>   `1` = 0))") in "user/all.php" at line 37.

Line 37 of "user/all.php"(my view file) is...

```
{% if (auth.renderFriendShip('1', '2', 'isThereRequestPending')) == 1 %}
```

My user model class (where this code is being run)

```
$matchThese = ['user_one' => "$user_one", 'user_two' => "$user_two", 'friendship_official', '0'];
$orMatchThese = ['user_one' => "$user_two", 'user_two' => "$user_one", 'friendship_official', '0'];
$query = $this->friendsList()
            ->where($matchThese)
            ->orWhere($orMatchThese)
            ->get();

return $query->count();
```

At the end of the day, my mass confusion is on the beginning of the running query, specificall the ("`users_friends`.`user_id` = 1 and `users_friends`.`user_id` is not null and") part because I am no-where in my code telling it to add this.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a listing of your tables please. This will help to find out what's going on.

Comment: @user3711213 my tables are 'users', 'users_friends', 'users_permissions'. If you need the columns too, ill screen shot them

Comment: Indeed that's what we need to see

Comment: @user3711213 sorry for such a delayed response... here are the 3 images (http://imgur.com/7rFGZsg,eeuFw2v,nD0jc3o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any 'user_id' field in the 'user_friends' table.
So the query fails because it refers to a column that do not exists.
So in your query you must use 'user_friends.id' which in this case will point to the id field in the user_friends table.

Comment: I totally agree with this, but why is it in my query? I didn't add it anywhere and that's the only part that is making my query result in error

Comment: You have probably in your code some relationship set between the tables.  Are you using some framework? Laravel, Codeigniter of something like that?

Comment: I am using Slim with Twig and Eloquent... and some other packages but nothing major

Comment: There actually is a relationship... its this code

## return $this->hasOne('HardcoreWars\User\UserFriends', 'user_id'); ##

My question now is can I make it to where that beginning query code is inexistant from here?

Comment: It is difficult to guess where the problem is without have a look at the code. Did You already try to change 'user_id' to 'id' in this relationship and run the query again?

Comment: yes, it gives me the same error but I suspect because I don't have any info added into that table (as in user info). The table is supposed to be empty until info is needed to be added in tho. Would you like me to upload the code to github?

Comment: I would like to, but I'm leaving tomorrow for the summer holidays and I will come back in three weeks. So I can not have a look at your code. Anyway the error you get has nothing to do with an empty table. This is a relationship related problem. Eloquent does much work for you in the background and follows automatically all the relations you have set in the models.